# Is it possible to enable automatic error highlighting in Geany?

Tags: geany

Is it possible to set up the Geany IDE so that it will highlight compiler errors automatically (like the Eclipse IDE for Java)? I've noticed that Geany doesn't highlight syntax errors in source code by default, and I want to enable this feature, if it exists.

Comment: There is a button for Lint on the Build menu but you have to check manually or develop a plugin that does. It does not by default